# Scilab error "Attempt to reference field of non-structure array."

Tags: matlab, scilab

I'm trying to import code from Matlab to Scilab and I'm getting an error on line 5. I have no idea what could be the matter.

Here is the code:

```
g1 = 9.8; v1 = 10:2:20;
theta = 50:10:80;
vTranspose = v1.';
thetaSind = sind(theta);
h1 = (vTranspose.ˆ2) * (thetaSind.ˆ2) / (2*g1); //Error here
table = [0, theta; vTranspose, h1]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `ˆ` is not the same as `^`, this sometimes happens when copy pasting from a pdf or some other source.

Comment: Oh God, thanks so much. I've been pulling my hair over this error for the past hours.